# recursive iterable template functions c++

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

I'm confused about how to pass type info down a recurrence chain.

The goal of the following code is to do something like python's `",".join(["a","b","c"])`, but recursively, so that I can join an array of arrays of arrays of... of strings, where there are as many delimiters as the structure is deep.

Here is my somewhat commented-out (in an attempt to get it to compile) code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <vector>


template <typename RAI>
std::string string_join(RAI begin, RAI end, std::string delimiter) {
    if (begin == end) { return ""; }
    std::string joint = std::to_string(*begin);
    begin++;
    for (; begin != end; begin++) {
        joint += delimiter + std::to_string(*begin);
    }
    return joint;
}


template <typename RAI, int depth>
struct string_join_recursive {
    std::string operator()(RAI iterator, std::string *delimiter, int *dimensions) {
        typedef typename std::iterator_traits<RAI>::value_type::iterator value_iterator_type;
        std::cout << typeid(value_iterator_type).name() << " " << typeid(std::begin(*iterator)).name() << std::endl;
        std::string joint = string_join_recursive<value_iterator_type, depth-1>(std::begin(*iterator), delimiter+1, dimensions+1);
        iterator++;
        for (int i=1; i<*dimensions; i++) {
            //joint += *delimiter + string_join_recursive<value_iterator_type, depth-1>(std::begin(*iterator), delimiter+1, dimensions+1);
            iterator++;
        }
        return "";//joint;
    }
};

template <typename RAI>
struct string_join_recursive<RAI,1> {
    std::string operator()(RAI iterator, std::string *delimiter, int *dimensions) {
        return string_join(iterator, iterator + *dimensions, *delimiter);
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> a;
    std::vector<int> b = {1,2,3};
    std::vector<int> c = {1,2,4};
    std::string delimiters[2] = {"\n",","};
    int dimensions[2] = {2, 3};
    std::cout << string_join_recursive<std::vector<std::vector<int>>::iterator, 2>()(a.begin(), delimiters, dimensions) << std::endl;
}
```

I'm no veteran c++ programmer, so this probably has more than one issue, but for the time being, it won't even compile.  Apparently `value_iterator_type` is not the type that I'm thinking it is as this program runs, but I'm not sure exactly what it is.  OTOH, when I comment out the line 5, it compiles, and the print line above it says that those two things are the same type.

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘string_join_recursive<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, 1>::string_join_recursive(std::vector<int>::iterator, std::__cxx11::string*, int*)’
         std::string joint = string_join_recursive<value_iterator_type, depth-1>(std::begin(*iterator), delimiter+1, dimensions+1);
```

Bonus points for ways to do this thing in a cleaner fashion.
More bonus points for ways to make this work with arbitrary iterables (arrays, etc)

Comment: The error messages following the one you showed, "candidate is..." will provide more information as to the reason for the substitution failure. Since your question fails to meet all the requirements for a [mcve], as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help], and the shown error message is incomplete, it's unlikely that anyone will be able to figure out an answer.

Comment: This code is verifiable and complete.  I might be able to chop out a few lines, but it's pretty minimal.  I will post the full error message, but this is the code that produces that error.

Comment: No, it is not complete. The definition of `string_join` is not found anywhere. Additionally, it clearly needs some header files, like `<vector>` and `<iostream>`. If it cannot be copy-pasted and the compilation attempt does not produce the claimed results, it is not complete, or verifiable. Fail.

Comment: oops.  This is a couple of files pasted together, so I missed the `string_join`.  Good catch.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sketch of how I would approach it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <type_traits>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

// this allows us to test if a element should be recursed into

template <typename iterable, typename tag = void>
struct is_iterable
{
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template <typename iterable>
struct is_iterable <iterable, std::void_t <decltype (std::begin (std::declval <iterable> ()))>>
{
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

template <typename iterable>
constexpr bool is_iterable_v = is_iterable <iterable>::value;

// visit elements of a tuple

template <size_t Index, typename visitor, typename ...types>
void visit_tuple (std::tuple <types...> const & Tuple, visitor && Visitor)
{
    Visitor (std::get <Index> (Tuple));

    constexpr auto nextIndex = Index + 1;

    if constexpr (nextIndex < sizeof... (types))
        visit_tuple <nextIndex> (Tuple, Visitor);
}

// this function generically walks the elements of a container, with an overload for tuples and pairs

template <typename container, typename visitor>
std::enable_if_t <is_iterable_v <container>>
visit_elements (container const & Container, visitor && Visitor)
{
    for (auto && Element: Container)
        Visitor (Element);
}

template <typename visitor, typename ...element_types>
void visit_elements (std::tuple <element_types...> const & Tuple, visitor && Visitor)
{
    if constexpr (sizeof... (element_types) > 0)
        visit_tuple <0> (Tuple, Visitor);
}

template <typename visitor, typename first_type, typename second_type>
void visit_elements (std::pair  <first_type, second_type> const & Pair, visitor && Visitor)
{
    Visitor (Pair.first);
    Visitor (Pair.second);
}

// type trait for testing if a value is "visitable"

struct dummy_visitor { template <typename type> void operator () (type &&); };

template <typename container, typename tag = void>
struct is_visitable
{
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template <typename container>
struct is_visitable <container, std::void_t <decltype (visit_elements (std::declval <container> (), dummy_visitor()))>>
{
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

template <typename container>
constexpr bool  is_visitable_v =  is_visitable <container>::value;

// this function walks each item and either emits it or recurses into it

template <typename iterable>
bool join_impl (std::ostream & os, char delim, bool emitted_anything, iterable const & Iterable)
{
  using std::begin;
  using std::end;

  visit_elements (Iterable, [&] (auto && Element) {

    if constexpr (!is_visitable_v <decltype (Element)>)
    {
        if (emitted_anything)
          os << delim;

        os << Element;

        emitted_anything = true;
    }
    else
    {
      emitted_anything = join_impl (os, delim, emitted_anything, Element);
    }

  });

  return emitted_anything;
}

// these are wrappers to adapt join_impl for different use cases

template <typename container>
struct joiner
{
    char delim;
    container const & Container;

    operator std::string () const { return to_string <char> (); }

    template <typename char_t>
    std::basic_string <char_t> to_string () const;
};

template <typename container>
std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, joiner <container> j)
{
    bool emitted_anything = false;
    join_impl (os, j.delim, emitted_anything, j.Container);
    return os;
}

template <typename container>
template <typename char_t>
std::basic_string <char_t> joiner <container>::to_string () const
{
    std::ostringstream os;
    os << *this;
    return os;
}

template <typename container>
std::enable_if_t <is_visitable_v <container>, joiner <container>>
join (char delim, container const & Container)
{
    return joiner <container> { delim, Container };
}

// test the streaming use case

int main ()
{
    std::vector <std::vector <std::tuple <int, float>>> x {
        { { 1, 1.0f }, { 2, 2.0f }},
        { { 3, 3.0f }, { 4, 4.0f }},
    };

    std::cout << join (',', x) << std::endl;
}
```

This should work only any recursion of things that support the standard iteration protocols. It also supports tuples and pairs. In can be extended to user define structures by defining a overload of `visit_elements` that visits each exposed field. The `is_iterable` type trait needs work to be more precise in its expected interface.

Comment: Was there a good reason to totally rewrite it?  Can you point out the problems with the original design?

Comment: @Scott I don't know that is was a good reason, but my approach works with arbitrarily nested containers without requiring knowledge of the depth up front. With a little effort, it could be extended to walk tuples or user defined structures where the depth is not uniform.

Comment: "without requiring knowledge of the depth up front" ----niiiiccceeeee

Comment: Thanks. I updated it to walk tuples too. The one missing piece is fine grain control over delimiters. From what I see of your use case, I would just walk the top level container independently in insert newlines there.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to clean up the errors.  I was merely miscalling a functor.  My original intent with this was to have it work for arrays as well, which it does not.  Anyway, this is bascially a csv-writer for csvs of arbitrary dimension.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <vector>

template <typename RAI>
std::string string_join(RAI begin, RAI end, std::string delimiter) {
    if (begin == end) { return ""; }
    std::string joint = std::to_string(*begin);
    begin++;
    for (; begin != end; begin++) {
        joint += delimiter + std::to_string(*begin);
    }
    return joint;
}

template <typename RAI, int depth>
struct string_join_recursive {
    std::string operator()(RAI iterator, std::string *delimiters, int *dimensions) {
        typedef typename std::iterator_traits<RAI>::value_type::iterator value_iterator_type;
        std::string joint = string_join_recursive<value_iterator_type, depth-1>()(std::begin(*iterator), delimiters+1, dimensions+1);
        iterator++;
        for (int i=1; i<*dimensions; i++) {
            joint += *delimiters + string_join_recursive<value_iterator_type, depth-1>()(std::begin(*iterator), delimiters+1, dimensions+1);
            iterator++;
        }
        return joint;
    }
};

template <typename RAI>
struct string_join_recursive<RAI,1> {
    std::string operator()(RAI iterator, std::string *delimiters, int *dimensions) {
        return string_join(iterator, iterator + *dimensions, *delimiters);
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a = {1,2,3};
    std::vector<int> b = {4,5,6};
    std::vector<int> c = {7,8,9};
    std::vector<int> d = {10,11,12};
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> e = {a,b};
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> f = {c,d};
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> g = {e,f};
    std::string delimiters[3] = {"\n",";",","};
    int dimensions[3] = {2, 2, 3};
    std::cout << string_join_recursive<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>::iterator, 3>()(g.begin(), delimiters, dimensions) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest some changes to ease usage and clean the code: [Demo](https://ideone.com/rsPHjY)

Comment: Oh yeah, you can get the end with `std::end`!  That's a good suggestion.